# How to make my script stop if the "person" hits a boundary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal

I am trying to make a grid in which a person can move, but stops only if he hits the boundaries.

[image: General grid outline]

He can either hit a boundary and stop, or keep walking until no more characters in the file are given. I am not sure how to approach the person stopping; I am a beginner and do not know if an array should be used, because the boundaries (length & width) should be random each time the script is run (except the East wall has a 5 tile gate each time).

```
    try: #file argument
        text = open(filename)
        lines = text.readlines()
        text.close()
    except:
        print("Error lacks reading permissions!", file=sys.stderr)
        exit()
    match=re.search("[nsew]", filename)
    if match:
        if 'n' in filename:
            y+=1
        elif 's' in filename:
            y-=1
        elif 'e' in filename:
            x+=1
        else:
            x-=1
    else:
        print("filename contains characters other than n, s, e and w. Please use a file that only contains these characters.")
        exit()
    if x == 0 and y == 0:
        counter+=1
    else:
        elephant=1 #placeholder
    if x == ((length-1)/2) and -2 < y < 2:
        print ("The walk was" steps "long, returned to the origin" counter "times. It ended because the drunk man reached the gate.")
    elif x == ((length-1)/2) and y > 2 and y < -2:
        print ("The walk was" steps "long, returned to the origin" counter "times. It ended because the drunk man reached the wall.")
    else:
        print ("The walk was" steps "long, returned to the origin" counter "times. It ended because the drunk man ran out of steps.")
```

Comment: How exactly will "person"s be represented?

Comment: It's just a person who walks around based on a sequence in a file.

Comment: First, shrink the `try/except` clause to cover _only_ the `open` statement. It masks all of your potential errors.

Comment: Thanks, found a syntax error that was being masked by the try/except clause